# Changing the case within Snipmate.vim snippets?

Tags: vim, snipmate

Is it possible to change the case of variable values within Snipmate snippets?

For example:

```
snippet dc
  def create
    @${1} = $1.new
  end
```

Should output:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new
end
```

I tried to use backticks to call a custom function:

```
snippet dc
  def create
    @${1} = `ToUpperCase('$1')`.new
  end
```

And defined this function in Vim:

```
function! ToUpperCase(str)
    let result = substitute(a:str, '\(\w\)', '\u\1', '')
    return result
endfunction
```

This doesn't work as it seems that Snipmate expands its $n variables *after* it has executed the backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a little hack to snipMate to allow the functionality I was looking for.

Put this code in autoload/snipMate.vim to the end of the s:RemoveSnippet() function (after the line #14):

```
let linecount = len(getline("1", "$"))
for linenum in range(1, linecount)
    let line = getline(linenum)
    let line = substitute(line, '\v\%uc\(([^)]+)\)', '\U\1\E', 'g')
    let line = substitute(line, '\v\%ucfirst\(([^)]+)\)', '\u\1', 'g')
    call setline(linenum, line)
endfor
```

Now you can define snippets like this:

```
snippet dc
  def create
    @${1:product} = %ucfirst($1).new
    %uc($1) = "This is Ruby %uc(constant) example."
  end
```

Output:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new
  PRODUCT = "This is Ruby CONSTANT example."
end
```

Notice that the replacement is not done in real time but after you "quit" the snippet.

Comment: SnipMate.vim fork, which includes this functionality, is now at GitHub: https://github.com/jarijokinen/snipmate.vim

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: I am the main author of UltiSnips.

For your interest and rollin-the-drum purposes, I present two snippet definitions for [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) which has been mentioned here before. Both do what the OP wants. The first one uses transformations (TextMate syntax):

```
snippet dc "create" b
def create
   @$1 = ${1/.*/\u$0/}.new
end
endsnippet
```

The second uses python code interpolation. For my tastes this is easier to read but it is a little more verbose.

```
snippet dc "create" b
def create
   @$1 = `!p snip.rv = t[1].title()`.new
end
endsnippet
```

Since version 1.3 UltiSnips comes with a script that can convert snipMate snippets, switching should therefore be easy.

Answer (score 3):

The current release of snipMate is not capable of performing transformations on the mirrored text. Look up `:help snipMate-disadvantages` where it says:

> Regex cannot be performed on variables, such as "${1/.*/\U&}"

If you really want this feature, you might want to try one of the other snippet plugins out there. [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) uses the same syntax for defining snippets, and claims to have all of the same features as TextMate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried UltiSnips once but it was missing something (don't remember what) and that's why I started to use snipMate. I think the hack below is enough for now.